# how to redirect with POST Variables from php?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, authentication, http-post

I wanted to make a login to a web application which apparently is done using POST
is in the intermediate validate php file 
The intermediate validate file would generate a ticket which would be the identifier throughout the  session
But how would I do pass the ticket as a post parameter? from the intermediate login validating file without DELAY??

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    function postRedirect()
  {





    document.forms['form'].submit();


  }   
  </script>


 <body onload="postRedirect();">

 <form name="form" action="home.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="ticket" value="<?php echo $ticket; ?>" />
</form>
</body>
```

Above given is my current code which works as for the functionality but has a significant delay in loading the Home Page
There should be a better solution to this issue and I'm looking forward to find that here and any other alternate way to achieve it. 
PS: Using session wouldn't be something that is feasible for me but please let me know if I dont have any other solution in regards to this
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: use php sessions instead of post

Comment: @morissette is there a way to do it without session??

Comment: your $ticket, that it is generated via a function,  will be used by your home.php, and this in the case of successfull connection, right ? can you generate $ticket immediatly after the success identification of the user and call directly home.php ?

Comment: @HalayemAnis that is exactly my requirement. But $ticket should be [assed as a post variable or encrypted somehow. Can't pass the ticket as a url (GET)parameter

Comment: you would need to use javascript to take the post and pass it via ajax to another script, i assume. Session would be better even if you passed via session then destroyed the session.

Comment: @morissette if I have to use session could you explain hoe to achieve that?How about running through the whole application which might get which might require javascript functions passing values. How could I do it with sessions??

Comment: Why is it you don't want to use session? Any solutions I have in mind are actually just re-inventing the session system. You need to have a secret data on server and something that connect that data with remote user. One way or another, that's session.

Comment: @TomášZato I ended up using session!!!